# Why to use mutex instead of boolean variable for thread synchronization?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, boolean, mutex

I'm trying to understand the multithreading programming in C.

I have doubt that as we uses MUTEXES for thread synchronization, why we can't use Boolean variable to block the critical area of code to be executed.

What is specialty of mutes over Boolean variable?

PS: Actually this question was asked in an interview.
So please share your knowledge about this.

Comment: Is this a question about any particular language? You're not getting language agnostic answers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that two threads could both see the Boolean value as available at the same time, and both would then assume that it's safe to continue.

For example, say you have this code:

```
bool myLock = false;  // visible to all threads

void someFunction()
{
    if (!myLock)
    {
        myLock = true;
        // do whatever
        // and then release the lock
        mylock = false;
    }
}
```

Now, imagine that two threads are executing. Thread A reads `myLock` and sees that it's `false`, so it goes on to the next instruction. At the same time, Thread B reads `myLock` and sees that it's `false`, because Thread A hasn't yet set it to `true`. So Thread B goes right ahead and takes the lock, too. At this point, both threads are executing the code that's supposed to be protected by a mutual exclusion lock.

It gets worse because Thread A finishes what it's doing and sets `mylock` back to `false` while Thread B is still executing. So another thread can come along and take the lock even though Thread B is still in there.

A mutex guarantees atomicity. That is, it guarantees that the check-and-update can only be done by a single thread at a time. So if you replace the boolean with a mutex, you have:

```
if (mutex.Acquire())
{
    // do stuff
    // then release the lock
    mutex.Release();
}
```

There's no chance that two threads can acquire the mutex simultaneously.

Comment: "the check-and-update can only be done by a single thread at a time." Getting down to the nitty-gritty, does that mean that a check can be done, and there is a context switch, but other threads know there is a check-and-update in place so they don't attempt? In otherwords I'm asking, is that how a mutex works, is it just naturally attomic or does it work by knowing that only thread can do a check-and-update and it's possible to be check-another thread comes in-and update, while in the other thread it knows a check-and-update is in progress so can't do it?

Comment: A mutex is naturally atomic. It uses a CPU instruction that does an atomic check-and-update. So if one thread starts to acquire the mutex, it's impossible for another to do so.

Answer (score 3):

If you tried to use a boolean as a "fake mutex", I could easily keep pointing out flaws in your implementation until you basically wound up re-inventing the mutex. A mutex is basically a boolean with all the extra stuff you need to use it for thread synchronization.

Answer (score 3):

```
int locked = 0;
void lock( void ) {
    while ( locked ) sleep_api( little );
    locked = 1;
    return;
}
```

This code is wrong, because two threads can simultaneously see 0 in the locked variable, and thinks they have the lock.

Comment: Nice example. What if only one thread will ever be writing to the boolean and another thread will be the only thread reading from the boolean? Would it be safe then?

Comment: It depends. What is the meaning for the boolean, what are the threads doing, depending of the boolean value?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, your proposal is not entirely clear. Let's say you have five threads all competing for the same resource. It is clear how you would use a mutex to ensure exclusive access. It is far from clear how you'd use a boolean variable for this.

That said, boolean variables can sometimes be used for synchronization. However, circumstances where this is applicable are limited, and there are caveats (for example, such variables generally need to be declared `volatile`).

Mutexes are applicable far more widely. It may be worth mentioning that in addition to (correctly) ensuring that only one thread can enter the protected section, they also act as [memory barriers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier).