# How to throttle method invocation in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, concurrency

```
class PublishService {
    public void longRunningPublish() {
        ...
    }
}
```

From different places in code, the method can be invoked.

```
caller1.longRunningPublish();
caller2.longRunningPublish();
...
callerN.longRunningPublish();
```

Question: how can I prevent `longRunningPublish` running concurrently? Each invocation should *stack* and be delay, and only start when the previous run has finished.

Could I do better than the following?

```
class PublishService {
    private boolean running;

        public void throttleLongRunningPublish() {
            while (running) {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
            }   
            
            running = true;
            
            try {
               longRunningPublish();
            } finally {
               running = false;
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not thread safe.
If you create multiple instances of PublishService and run them concurrently the boolean variable has no effect.
If your instance of PublishService is a singleton and the same class is executed by different threads there there is no guarantee that the method will be executed serially because multiple thread could enter the method before reaching the instruction:

```
running = true;
```

This is a simple example than handles serialization if there are multiple instances of the same class along with a "demo" main

```
public class PublishService {
private static final Logger logger= LoggerFactory.getLogger(PublishService.class.getName());

private static final Lock lock=new ReentrantLock();
public void longRunningPublish() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        logger.info("{} longRunningPublish before sleep",Thread.currentThread().getId());
        Thread.sleep(500);
        logger.info("{} longRunningPublish after sleep",Thread.currentThread().getId());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    ExecutorService executor=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        executor.submit(() -> {
            PublishService publishService = new PublishService();
            publishService.longRunningPublish();
        });
    }
}
```

}

If the class is a singleton you can remove the static qualifier of the lock variable.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent concurrent access, you need to lock the resource while it is being used with something like a [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html). If you need to guarantee in-order access, you can use the constructor `ReentrantLock(boolean fair)` with fair set to `true`. Otherwise, you can use a basic ReentractLock or the [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) property.

Comment: Order doesn't matter. Is there an advantage of `ReentrantLock` over a simple boolean?

Comment: Yes, the use of a boolean here isn't thread-safe. N threads calling throttleLongRunningPublish() concurrently could all read the value of `running` as false and all continue to invoke longRunningPublish(). The first thread to exit longRunningPublish() will set the value back to `false`, even though the other thread(s) are still running. A lock guarantees that only one thread has access. You can see the explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19547653/15701595 for more details (it's written for C, but it's the same concept)

Answer (score 0):

I found a neat way with `Semaphore`:

```
class PublishService {
    private static final Semaphore lock = new Semaphore(1);

    public void throttleLongRunningPublish() {
        try {
            lock.tryAcquire(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        
            longRunningPublish();
        } finally {
            lock.release();
        }
    }
}
```